# Mix and Mixture

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

What is considered the correct usage of *mix* versus *mixture*?

As an example, is either of these two sentences considered to be more correct grammatically than the other?

1) *The trip was a mix of hiking and climbing*

2) *The trip was a mixture of hiking and climbing*

To my ear either is acceptable, but I presume one is better than the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The differences between *mix* and *mixture* are subtle.

A [*mix*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mix) of something is often descriptive of the make-up or components of a mixture:

> The castle was built from a mix of sand and water.

A [*mixture*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mixture), on the other hand, is the thing that is mixed:

> The cake mixture is often a mix of eggs, flour, and oil.

There is a lot of wiggle room in usage and the distinction of when to use one or another is fuzzy.  A general rule of thumb is to use *mix* when naming the individual parts, and *mixture* to describe the whole.

In the examples you gave, I think both would be acceptable, because you are either talking about a mix of hiking and camping that make up the trip, or the trip's "mixture" of hiking and camping.

Comment: *Mix* can also be used as a verb: "Mix 1/4 flour, 1 egg, 1/4 cup milk into a small bowl, and then..."

Comment: That is true, but in this example he is asking about the noun.

Comment: Great explaination, cheers :-)

Comment: There’s also ***admixture***: 1. The action or process of mingling one substance with another, or of adding as an ingredient; the fact of being so mingled. 2. That which is mixed with anything; an alloy, an alien element.

Comment: I would also use "mix" when the ingredients were *designed* to go together, and "mixture" when it's more customised.

Answer (score 0):

*Mixture* tends to be reserved for physical things, but they are generally interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

I would say they are completely interchangeable in this case. When used as a noun, mix is a synonym of mixture.

Answer (score -1):

*Mixture* can be used to mean:

- a substance made by mixing other substances together
- [a mixture of] a combination of different qualities, things, or emotions in which the component elements are individually distinct
- a person regarded as a combination of qualities and attributes
- the charge of gas or vapor mixed with air that is admitted to the cylinder of an internal combustion engine

*Mix* can be used to mean:

- two or more different qualities, things, or people placed, combined, or considered together
- a group of people of different types within a particular society or community
- a commercially prepared mixture of ingredients for making a particular type of food or a product such as concrete
- an image or sound produced by the combination of two separate images or sounds

In the specific case, either *mix* or *mixture* can be used, but they are not perfectly equivalent, as in other cases you use *mix*, and in other different cases you use *mixture*.

Answer (score -1):

A mixture is the result of mixing. That is why you buy a cake mix, but not a cake mixture.

Accordingly, version 1 is a viable description of a trip that was planned, while version 2 is apt for a trip that was actually taken.

Comment: Do you have any references/citations to back you up?  Also, what does this answer clarify that hasn't been fully answered by the accepted answer written 6 years ago?

Answer (score -2):

I would like put it in a very simple way

1) Mix - is always a Verb ( Mixing of two substances together )

2) Mixer - is a Noun ( A device / Machine used for Mixing two / more substances together )

3) Mixture - always a Noun ( A substance made by mixing two / more substances together )